# junit running dependent project test cases with Maven

Tags: maven, junit

I need to run dependent project junit test cases.

I have project called Test-A and another project called Test-B. Both are maven based project and having Junit test classes.

Now, I want to run junit test cases of Test-A from the project Test-B. I have included Test-A project in Test-B with maven dependency tag.

To run this I have used new JUnitCore().run, but it doesn't run properly if I have some values to read from the xml file in Test-A.

I have used a plugin called fail safe with surefire, but no output.

Is there anyway to run these kind of situation?

If not possible, Do I need to do any integration testing framework such as Selenium webdriver or other application?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that names of test classes you run match patterns.

> By default, the [Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> "`**/IT*.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>   filenames that start with "IT". "`**/*IT.java`" - includes all of its
>   subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "IT".
>   "`**/*ITCase.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>   filenames that end with "ITCase".
>
> By default, the [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> "`**/Test*.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>   filenames that start with "Test". "`**/*Test.java`" - includes all of
>   its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
>   "`**/*TestCase.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>   filenames that end with "TestCase".

Otherwise, adjust patterns in configuration.

Comment: this will work only, if test cases and project are in together, it will not run the test cases of another project. i.e If I want to run test cases of Test-A from Test-B, this feature will not support.